# Does ASP.Net MVC run on top of ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does ASP.Net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005 has the possibility of working with MVC or I have to move to VS2008 and asp.net 3.5?

Comment: The lack of anonymous types would make it beyond painful.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not supported. The post that Scott wrote might be outdated. Even following that post, it might not work now due to some recent changes. You're best off upgrading to .NET 3.5 as who knows what might break trying to build an ASP.NET MVC site for 2.0

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported but you can read up on how to do it here...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx

Comment: [this doesn't work anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231891/does-asp-net-mvc-run-on-top-of-asp-net-2-0/238871#238871).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, I asked Scott Hanselman to update his blog with the fact that his technique no longer works. You'll have to upgrade to ASP.NET 3.5 to use ASP.NET MVC. (ASP.NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 is not, however, required, though it will work just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't intended to work but I remember reading something from Scott Hanselman saying it may be possible with a bit of hacking.  It would be dodgy as though.